# why is shouldChangeCharactersInRange delegate method never called?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/04/27/how-to-program-an-ios-text-field-that-takes-only-numeric-input-or-specific-characters-with-a-maximum-length/) on how to restrict `textField` to a certain length and character set.

Here is my code, and yet the delegate isn't called:

VC class: this is called (verified while debugging)

```
var textManager = TextManager()
@IBOutlet weak var enterName_text: UITextField!


func onVideDidLoad() {
...
    enterName_text.placeholder = StringConstans.name
    enterName_text.delegate = textManager
    }
```

TextManager class:

```
import Foundation

public class TextManager: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.characters.count == 0 {
            return true
        }
         let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)


            return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") &&
                prospectiveText.characters.count <= 6
          }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works for me. Have you checked `textManager` is not nil, and your IBOutlet is hooked up properly?

Comment: It's not nil and setting a value to its text property works. so it's also hooked ok. I;m using xcode 7 and ios with swift 2.0

Comment: @matt I have created an textManager instance and set `enterName_text.delegate = textManager` or I'm not understanding you correctly?

Comment: It works only when i set the VC to be the delegate and write the handle method also in the VC. can it be because of "public" identifier in the TextManager?

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. How does yours differ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    let textManager = TextManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = textManager
    }
}

public class TextManager: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("should")
        if string.characters.count == 0 {
            return true
        }
        let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") &&
            prospectiveText.characters.count <= 6
    }
}

extension String {
    func containsOnlyCharactersIn(matchCharacters: String) -> Bool {
        let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: matchCharacters).invertedSet
        return self.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean work? I want to disallow special chars like "$%%" and the simulator and real device allow me to add this

Comment: It works only when i set the VC to be the delegate and write the handle method also in the VC. can it be because of "public" identifier in the TextManager?

Comment: It works in the sense that "should" gets printed meaning the delegate gets called. I don't have your containsOnlyCharactersIn extension. And as you can see, I have not set the VC to be the delegate - TextManager is a separate class, it just happens to be in the same file. It works equally well when in a separate file, although you have to change `import Foundation` to `import UIKit` - how come you didn't need to without a compilation error?

Comment: It works in the sense that "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" code is executed. No matter what's the result. Again it works when I set the VC to be the delegate, not textManager

Comment: Your question says your delegate is not being called. Are you now saying it is, but the result is wrong. I took the `containsOnlyCharactersIn` code from the tutorial, and my code now works 100% - "abc" accepted, "!@#" ignored.